# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, facebook

In Facebook, I want to listen `userContentWrapper` class to check if there is new status loaded in the news feed, but I got an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

MutationObserver:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    for(var i=0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++){
      var added = mutation.addedNodes[i].getElementsByClassName("userContentWrapper"); // error in this line
            if(added){

            }

    }
  });    
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bx6or2pc/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny so there is no problem for my code? what is #some-id?

Comment: that is the element which is being observed... I used jQuery to add new elements to the target element so that the mutation observer will get called

Answer (score 0):

It's because some of mutations are not an objects, they are simple text, which hasn't method  `getElementsByClassName`